# Running Hapi.js in Nodewekit

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, hapi.js

Has anyone run Hapi application inside Nodewebkit?

This is my package.json:`{
  "name": "nw",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "node-main": "nwindex.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "webkit": {
    "page-cache":false
  },
  "author": "",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": true,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 500
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "nw": "^0.12.2",
    "pretty-bytes": "^1.0.2"
  }
}`

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My App</title>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">  
   var gui = require('nw.gui');
   var win = gui.Window.get();

   var fs = require("fs");
   gui.App.clearCache();


  setTimeout (function () {
     window.location = 'http://localhost:3000';
  },1000)
```

And this is my nwindex.js ([Getting started from official site](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/getting-started)):

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000 });

server.route({
method: 'GET',
path: '/',
handler: function (request, reply) {
    reply('Hello, world!');
    }
  });

  server.route({
   method: 'GET',
   path: '/{name}',
   handler: function (request, reply) {
       reply('Hello, ' + encodeURIComponent(request.params.name) + '!');
    }
  });
  server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
       throw err;
    }
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
  });
```

Problem is when I start the NW, it instantly exists. I can see what is going on inside.

I have removed code line by line to see hwere is the problem, and I have narrowed it down to initial calling line:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
```

It seems that crashes the application. Any help is appreaciated.
Nodewebkit version I use:

- nw.js v0.12.3
- io.js v1.2.0
- Chromium 41.0.2272.76

After more tests, it seems this is maeking a problem:

```
server.start((err) => {
```

This => operator. How to byspass it?

Comment: server.start(function(err) {

Comment: Could that be the whole problem? When I run NW in debug mode, I see also  Items.serial(this.connections, (connectionItem, next) => { SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>....

Comment: What version of hapi are you using?

Comment: I just got the latest version.

Comment: This won't work with node-webkit as that is built with older version of node which doesn't allow you to use that syntax.  Use a compatible version of hapi and node-webkit.  I can't remember the last version of hapi before the switch to node v4, I think it was v9.

Comment: I have used babel to transpile most current version of Hapi to Ecma5. And it appears to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is the ES6 arrow function which isn't available in the version of node you are using.   [ES6 in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/)

```
server.start(function(err){

    if (err) {
       throw err;
    }
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```